# Send AT+COPS command to android phone

Tags: android, bluetooth, at-command

I am trying to send AT+COPS=3,0 and AT+COPS? command to my android phone from another android emulator(androidx86). I am sending this command to query the operator name. But I am not getting any response for this command. I am getting response for some other command(AT+CIND?). But not getting for any AT+COPS command. I have searched google and not getting proper results to understand why there is no response.

Can someone tell me why there is no response for AT+COPS command?

Comment: Have you tested with `AT+COPS=?` as well?

Comment: Yes. I tested with AT+COPS=? also.

Comment: Can someone please help me on this? Any idea why it is not working?